# How to share a video on YouTube with password protection on it

Tags: youtube

I'd like to share a video on YouTube with password protection on it.

Is that possible?

I know I can share a video with a contact that has a Google account, but in this instance I want anyone with the password to be able to access it. Delisting the video isn't suitable either it needs to be password protected.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube does not have this feature. You may want to use Vimeo or a self hosted solution instead.